# Magento 2.2.7 Order confirmation email missing payment method

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.7

In my Magento 2.2.7, we have three payment methods Eway, Zipmoney, and PayPal express checkout. All payment methods are working fine. However, in the order confirmation email, the payment method is missing when we process the payment through PayPal. For all other methods its coming good. 
Thank you for your help.